# Convert a character to 16 bits of unicode encoding

Tags: python, unicode

I have a UTF-8 character and I want to convert it into 16 bits of unicode encoding. How to do it?

Unicode of character can be obtained by reading the file where it is written and using repr() like:

```
import codecs
f = codecs.open("a.txt",mode='rb',encoding='utf-8')
r = f.readlines()
for i in r:
    print i,repr(i)
```

Output:

```
پٹ u'\ufeff\u067e\u0679'
```

Now how can I get the 16 bits of unicode encoding for `u'\ufeff\u067e\u0679'`?

Comment: "Unicode encoding" is not a correct term.  Are you talking about UCS-2, UTF-16 or Unicode Code Points?

Comment: Worth also noting that the 0xfeff bit is just acting as a byte order mark here, it's not part of the text as such.

Comment: Does not look like utf-8 from here. The `\u` usually denotes a unicode code-point. From there you can encode it in different formats but it is unclear what you are trying to do. Please try and explain your problem in a bit more detail.

Answer (score 3):

In order to get the unicode *codepoint*, simply call [`ord`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#ord):

```
import io
f = io.open("a.txt", mode='r', encoding='utf-8')
for line in f:
    print (line, repr(line), ' '.join(str(ord(c)) for c in line),
                  ' '.join('{0:b}'.format(ord(c)) for c in line))
```

There is no one unicode *encoding*. If you're looking for the UTF-16 representation of a codepoint (which *can be more than 16 bits long*), simply call

```
u'\ufeff\u067e\u0679'.encode('utf-16')
```

Comment: i wanted a 16 bit binary representation for my unicode like for unicode 'U+0623' we have binary representation '11011000 10100011'

Comment: Why do you need the binary representation?

Comment: @user1593134 Added binary representation. Since Unicode spans more than 100000 > 2¹⁶ characters, the representation is not necessarily 16 bits long.

Comment: You won't get an actual representation of the underlying utf-16 data (assuming that the OP wanted UTF-16, which has still yet to be clarified), as you said, ord() is giving you the code-point not the actual bytes beneath the encoding. In fact, for anything outside of the 7-bit ASCII range the data won't look like any standard Unicode representation (at least I don't think it will).

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> a=u'\ufeff\u067e\u0679'
>>> a
u'\ufeff\u067e\u0679'
>>> a.encode("utf-16")
'\xff\xfe\xff\xfe~\x06y\x06'
```

The final line is the string you want.

Comment: how can i convert this unicode into 16 bit binary form.

Answer (score 0):

So, if your string is in `s`:

```
s_enc = s.encode("utf-16")
hex_string = "".join([format(i, "X").rjust(2,"0") for i in s_enc])
bin_string = "".join([format(i, "b").rjust(8,"0") for i in s_enc])
```

I think this is what you're after? (Tested in py3k, but should work in 2 I think).

Edit: needs a slight modification for Python 2x:

```
s_enc = s.encode("utf-16")
hex_string = "".join([format(ord(i), "X").rjust(2,"0") for i in s_enc])
bin_string = "".join([format(ord(i), "b").rjust(8,"0") for i in s_enc])
```

But, either way the key thing is to call encode() first to convert it to your chosen encoding (which isn't clear from your question, but reading between the lines, is UTF-16)

Comment: Perhaps I've missed something in py3k evolution, but isn't `'a'.rjust(2,"0")` equivalent to `'a'.zfill(2)`?

Comment: Yes, I think it is, I didn't realise that zfill works with arbitrary strings though - thought it might dislike the hex characters - the docs say "Return the *numeric* string left filled with zeros..." so I thought the hex characters might upset things - apparently not. So yes, you could just use zfill(2) or zfill(8) in my example if you wanted. I think the key thing with zfill is that it handles a negative sign properly - not an issue in my code I don't think.